# Trying to get property of non-object in Prestashop 1.6.1.11 Webox module

Tags: php, json, object

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/....................../modules/webox/webox.php on line 354

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/......................./webox/webox.php on line 393

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/......................../webox/webox.php on line 393

---

The code: 346-414

346 class WeboxClass{

347  public $total_count = 0;

```
public $json;
public function __construct($json = "") {
    if(strlen($json) == 0){
        $json = $this->downloadAutomatakAndReturn();
    }
    $this->json = json_decode($json);
```

354        $this->total_count = $this->json->total_count;}

```
public function downloadAutomatakAndReturn(){
    $tmp_dir = ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') ? ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') : (is_callable('sys_get_temp_dir') ? sys_get_temp_dir() : '');

    if (!is_file($tmp_dir.'/validboltlista.json') || filemtime($tmp_dir.'/validboltlista.json')+86400<time()) {
        $jsonData=file_get_contents('https://api-hu.easypack24.net/v4/machines?type=0');
        file_put_contents($tmp_dir.'/validboltlista.json', $jsonData, LOCK_EX);
}else{
        $jsonData=file_get_contents($tmp_dir.'/validboltlista.json');
    }
    return $jsonData;
}

function getAllAutomataAsOptions($selectedAutomata){
    $result = "";
    $automatak = array();
    foreach($this->getAutomatakByTelepules("") as $automata){
        /* @var $automata WeboxItem */
        $cim = $automata->getAddress_city() . " " . $automata->getAddress_post_code() . ", " . $automata->getAddress_street() . " " . $automata->getAddress_building_no();
        $automatak[$automata->getId()] = array(
            'text' => $cim . " (" . $automata->getId() . ")", 
            'id' => $automata->getId(), 
            'map' => $automata->getMinimap(), 
            'info' => $automata->getLocation_description()
        );
    }
    sort($automatak);
    foreach($automatak as $s){
        $selected = (strlen($selectedAutomata) > 1 && $s['id'] == $selectedAutomata ? "selected='selected'" : "");
        $result .=  "<option value='".$s['id']."' data-map='".$s['map']."' data-info='".$s['info']."' ".$selected.">".$s['text']."</option>\n";
    }
    return $result;

}

function getAutomatakByTelepules($telepules){
    $result = array();
```

393        foreach($this->json->_embedded->machines as $id => $json){

```
        if($json->address->city == $telepules || strlen($telepules) == 0){
            $result[$id] = new WeboxItem($json);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

function getAutomataByID($id){
    foreach($this->json->_embedded->machines as $id => $json){
        if($json->id == $id){
            return @new WeboxItem($json);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function getTotalCount() {
    return $this->total_count;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Sorry, I have a question: What is the solution?  The  webpage front  debub notice: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/....................../modules/webox/webox.php on line 354

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/......................./webox/webox.php on line 393

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/......................../webox/webox.php on line 393

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct.

The problem is with the server. I have installed to another server the prestashop and installed the webox plugin. There is working.

But the problem not with the php.ini file and htaccess file. I have copied all file from one server to another server but not solved the problem.

Summ: The code is correct.